# Vue import same component twice/ Vue event from child only to root, not to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-component, laravel-blade

**What I have**

I'm importing the same component twice. This component is used to display a dropdown with collections.
When an item in the dropdown is selected, an event is triggered.
The component is imported in `list.js` and in `BulkActions.vue`.

**The problem**

An event is fired when a collection in the dropdown is selected. It then triggers an event using `$emit`. Somehow this event is only catched in `list.blade.php` and not in `BulkActions.vue`.
For both dropdowns (loading from the same component) there should be a different behaviour.
I have no idea why this happens or why the event is only catched at my root.

**What I've tried**

I've tried to pass an additional `prop` in the HTML to have a "variable event name", but that didn't work. I've tried various ways of importing the component as well.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**The files**

`list.blade.php`:

```
    <div class="media-list-navbar mt-3 mb-3">
        <shown-results :text="resultText"></shown-results>

        <search-bar @update-filters="updateFilters"></search-bar>

        <document-types @update-filters="updateFilters"></document-types>

        <collection-dropdown eventname="update-filters"
                             @update-filters="updateFilters"></collection-dropdown>


        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <bulk-actions @select-all="selectAll"
                  @deselect-all="deselectAll"
                  :items="items"
                  :multiselect="multiSelect"></bulk-actions>
```

`BulkActions.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="multiselect-list-navbar mt-3 mb-3" v-if="multiselect">
        <div class="float-left">
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                    @click="$emit('deselect-all')">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-times"></i> {{ Lang.get('media/item.index.list.multi-select.deselect-all') }}
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                    @click="$emit('select-all')">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-check"></i> {{ Lang.get('media/item.index.list.multi-select.select-all') }}
            </button>
        </div>

        <bulk-collection
            @update-filters="doSomething"></bulk-collection>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Bulk",
        props: {
            multiselect: Boolean,
            items: Array
        },
        components: {
            'bulk-collection': () => import('./Collections')
        },
        methods: {
            doSomething() {
                console.log(this.items)
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

`list.js`

```
import MediaItem from '../components/MediaItem';
import UploadModal from '../components/media/UploadModal';
import ItemDetail from '../components/media/ItemDetail';
import ShownResults from '../components/media/list/ShownResults';
import SearchBar from '../components/media/list/SearchBar';
import DocumentTypes from '../components/media/list/DocumentTypes';
import {default as CollectionDropdown} from '../components/media/list/Collections';
import Order from '../components/media/list/Order';
import BulkActions from '../components/media/list/BulkActions';

if (document.getElementById('media-list')) {
    const mediaList = new Vue({
        el: '#media-list',
        components: {
            MediaItem,
            ShownResults,
            SearchBar,
            UploadModal,
            ItemDetail,
            DocumentTypes,
            CollectionDropdown,
            Order,
            BulkActions
        },
[...]
```

`Collections.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="dropdown float-left">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown">
            {{ Lang.get('media/item.index.list.filters.collections.title') }}
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" ref="collectionDropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-item no-pseudo">
                <input type="search"
                       class="form-control"
                       name="search"
                       :placeholder="Lang.get('media/item.index.list.filters.collections.filter')"
                       v-model="query"
                       @keyup="search">
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-item last-item no-pseudo">
                <alert type="warning">
                    <template v-slot:body>
                        {{ Lang.get('media/item.index.list.filters.collections.none-filter') }}
                    </template>
                </alert>
            </div>
            <div v-for="item in list"
                 class="dropdown-item"
                 v-if="!item.hidden">
                <span class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           class="custom-control-input"
                           name="collection[]"
                           :checked="item.checked"
                           :id="item.slug"
                           :value="item.id"
                           @change="selectItem">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" :for="item.slug">
                        {{ item.name }}
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Alert from '../../partials/Alert';

    export default {
        name: "Collections",
        components: {
            Alert
        },
        data() {
            return {
                displayAmount: 10, // amount of items displayed without search
                list: [],
                query: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            /**
             * Return an array of selected items only
             */
            checked() {
                return this.list.filter(item => {
                    return item.checked === true;
                })
            }
        },
        methods: {
            /**
             * Mark an item as selected
             */
            selectItem(e) {
                let selectedId = e.target.value;

                this.markItem(selectedId);
            },
            /**
             * Mark an item from the list as selected
             *
             * @param {Number} itemId
             */
            markItem(itemId) {
                this.list.forEach(item => {
                    if (item.id === parseInt(itemId)) {
                        item.checked = !item.checked;
                    }
                });

                this.$emit('update-filters', {
                    props: this.checked.map(item => item.id).join(',')
                });
            },
            /**
             * Search in the current URL for collection ids
             */
            markItemsFromUrl() {
                let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

                if (urlParams.has('collection')) {
                    let urlFilters = urlParams.get('collection').split(','); // split url parameters

                    urlFilters.forEach(itemId => {
                        this.markItem(itemId);
                    });
                }
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchList();
            this.markItemsFromUrl();

            /**
             * Prevent Bootstrap dropdown from closing after clicking inside it
             */
            $(this.$refs.collectionDropdown).on('click.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Below is a GIF animation to demonstrate the problem. The first dropdown (the one on the top) has normal behaviour. The second one (that appears later on) does not. When clicking the second one, an event of the first one is happening.

[image: https://imgur.com/PvxUVCm]

Comment: "Somehow this event is only catched in list.blade.php and not in BulkActions.vue"  that's how it should work. May be I'm not getting your question. With `$emit` you are telling parent vue component that some action has to be taken from child.

Comment: I don't see where you are importing the same component twice. I see `Collections` in `list.blade.php` which is one component and in `BulkActions.vue`, which is another component.

Comment: @The_ehT Sorry, I've updated my question. I've added the `Collections.vue` file in it as well now. I did also notice that my `BulkActions.vue` still had some test code in it so I've updated that event listener as well.

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan I thought so as well, but the event is not catched in my `BulkActions.vue`. I've added a GIF animation to show what is happening.

Comment: Did you try avoiding the dynamic component import on `BulkActions`? An update your `doSomething` to actually print the `event` and not the prop `this.items`

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan What do you mean by "Did you try avoiding the dynamic component import on BulkActions?" The `doSomething` method is never called

Comment: Replacing `components: {'bulk-collection': () => import('./Collections')}` with `import BulkCollection from './Collections; components : {BulkCollection}` Not sure, if this could solve your problem. The thing is when using dynamic imports, Vue looks for caches, if its already loaded. And with what I have suggested, Webpack would pack that in the module and Vue won't be looking for cached instances. Everything else looks fine with your code. And if this does'nt work, please add the code updating the `multiSelect`.

Comment: I tried to import it both ways but it doesn't help